# Cannot call Action within another Action

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk

I am having trouble understanding this behaviour

I have an `action` defined like this

```
import { whatever } from './kitty';

export const onDone = foo => dispatch => {
    whatever(foo);
    dispatch({
        type: ON_DONE,
    });
};
```

and `whatever()` is defined like this

```
export const whatever = foo => dispatch => {
    console.log('I DO NOT GET LOGGED');
    dispatch({
        type: DO_WHATEVER,
        payload: foo
    });
};
```

I expect `whatever()` to be executed, but it is not. Why is that?

Comment: In short, the action is two functions: First function accepts foo as args and returns dispatch and second function invokes/dispatches the action with args. Assuming you’re using redux thunks, you should be dispatching your actions: `dispatch(whatever(foo))`, which invokes the second function for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `onDone` and `whatever` here are *not* "actions", they are "action creators". They are functions that return an action ("thunk actions" in this case). An action here being something that can be dispatched to the redux store.

Them being action creators means: if you call them, you have an action, but that's like writing a letter. You now have a letter. It will be lying around on your table until you *actually do something with it*.

What do you do with an action for it to have any effect in redux? You dispatch it to the store.

So you would have to actually dispatch the action created by your `whatever` action creator:

```js
export const onDone = foo => dispatch => {
    dispatch(whatever(foo));
    dispatch({
        type: ON_DONE,
    });
};
```

PS: another answer suggests to call `whatever(foo)(dispatch)`. While that *technically* works and is part of what the redux-thunk middleware does internally, it does not fit the redux data flow model and is not the intended way of usage by the authors of the library. Please don't do this.

Comment: @HMR I'm a redux maintainer. Thunks should be dispatched, not called.

Comment: That is literally what the thunk middleware is made for. To have actions that are executed as functions. https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic#fetching-todos-from-a-server
If you don't dispatch them, you would not need the middleware. Then you also would not need to write them in the "currying action creator style", but just as functions. And they would be pretty much out of the redux data flow cycle.

Comment: @HMR PS: of yourse you can also do `dispatch(whatever(foo)).then(...)` or `const ret = await dispatch(whatever(foo))` - the thunk middleware trnsports the return value of the thunk action through `dispatch`.

Comment: @HMR Dispatching a thunk - like dispatching an action - leaves it up to the store what to do with that thunk/action. The store (read: a middleware) could decide to execute the thunk or another middleware could decide *not* to execute the thunk and for example return a memoized value from a former dispatch of the same thunk. (just as an example, I'm aware that in practice that is almost impossible)
It fits with the model of redux dataflow of *dispatching an event and having the store decide what to do on it*.

Comment: The idea of thunks was to create something that looks - from the perspective of the dispatching unit - exactly like a normal action.
If you want to call a function and pass dispatch and getStore into it, that is fine - but at that point, there is no reason to write that function as a thunk in the first place. Instead of `x => dispatch => { ... }`, that function could have a much easier signature like `(x, dispatch) => { ... }`.

Comment: Of course you can call a thunk by hand. But that was not the way that the authors of redux-thunk intended it to be used. You can also manipulate the DOM by hand in a React component, but also that is not the way the react authors intended their library to be used.
So it might be fine in edge cases. But it should definitely not be taught as "the way to do something" on a platform like StackOverflow except if it is really necessary in the context of the question.

Comment: And "I am a redux maintainer" was an answer to "Not sure why you think that is not the way to do it". I know the source of redux, related libraries and most of our documentation by heart, so I feel qualified to answer on how the authors of those libraries intended it to be used.

Comment: Adding another more practical and less philosophical reason to the mix: `whatever` could at any point in time change their signature to also use the third thunk argument, `extraArg`, which would break all manual calls but still stay valid on dispatch.

Comment: Sorry for this to be such a long conversation, I will delete the comments later but I think it made it clear why one way is better than the other because of: 1. design point - the store should descide what to do with actions. 2. later implementation of extra arguments in thunk. 3. Middleware will not be executed when calling other thunks directly. This would give future readers of your question a better understanding of why they should not do it. A small correction on `and is what redux does internally` should be `and is what redux-thunk middleware does internally`

Comment: Did some miror editing. You're free to add some more edit suggestions, but since this is more of a side remark that does not really touch the core of the question asked, I think the answer is fine as it it. If someone really wants to get into the details, these comments should be a good starting point on that, but I'm sure there are already other questions that ask this more directly and have more fleshed-out answers already.